# Could the Authorization Server return the code directly to the client instead of using a redirect in OAuth2 Autorization code flow?

Tags: oauth2

For Authorization code grant flow, [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-56) says the authorization server will send back the code to the redirect_uri specified.

I believe it means the browser will recieve a URL like http://webapp/?code=xyz

Now, the code in the browser will send the code to the client app so that the client will ask, using the code, an access token to the autorization server

That's where my question comes in. I think that returning the code to the user-agent is not secure

What if it was only returned to the client so that it can process the code to obtain an access token ?
Is is at all possible ?

Answer (score 0):

We have several sides in OAuth2 authorization code grant exchange

- OAuth Client - an application that want to be granted access
- Authorization Server - entity managing access
- Resource Owner (End User) with his user agent - person making decision to grant access (or not)

Now to initiate the flow Client captures Resource Owner's user agent and redirects it to Authorization server endpoint - passing scope of required access. The redirect is a mechanism to pass both scope of the request and actual, captured user to whom the request is addressed.

After the Resource Owner makes the decision it have to be passed back to the Client. OAuth2 uses second redirect for that and there are several benefits

- The Resource Owner user agent (browser) is back on Client's site and can continue working with it
- The Client can use cookies and other mechanism to confirm that the returning user is the same that one in initial redirect.
- As to obtain token the Client need some secret information, the leaking of code to the user does not open it to abuse

With direct server-to-server call instead first two points would be hart to achieve - for very limited security gain.

Comment: I will read your answer again. I did not undertand everything. But you are saying in both case the Auth Server will give the code directly to the Client ? What would be the use of the redirect then ? What does the user-agent do when it's redirected anyway ? I'll still confused here. Resource owner receives the code or is it the client... I'm confused lol

Comment: From the end - the resource owner (usually) is the person that is the person that authorizes (or not) the access. The client is an application that want to get access. In redirect user agent receives some URL and opens it. The information contained in URL is know to all three parties (server sending redirect, user agent, target server) and it is trivial to modify user agent to capture the URL instead of sending it to the target server. I will try to clarify my answer but it may take some time.

Comment: This is so true. The three parties receive the token. I was wondering how to give another adress to the user-agent since I don't want the auth code to be known by it.

Answer (score 0):

> I think that returning the code to the user-agent is not secure

Why not? The code is completely useless on its own (without the client secret or PKCE code verifier) if the PKCE extension is used, as is now recommended for all user-facing flows. The only threat is if an external party (attacker) obtains the code and is able to spoof to the client that the attacker is in fact the user (or at least their browser/other user agent), which PKCE mitigates since the code will be associated with a different code_verifier/code_challenge pair. Since the code is (supposed to be) single-use and very short-lived besides, the window for doing this is extremely short even without PKCE. It is also possible in most cases to avoid even exposing the code in a URL (which is slightly insecure, in that they are often logged and may briefly appear in a URL bar) by getting the user agent (browser) to POST the code to the redirect URL rather than doing a GET request, if that's your concern, but again, PKCE renders that consideration moot anyhow.

Besides that, the basic idea as described isn't very practical. Suppose Alice and Bob are both users on client Foo, and they (through Foo) make authorization requests to authorization server Bar. Bar verifies the identities and access authorization of Alice and Bob, and then... tells Foo that Alice and Bob have both authorized it to access their accounts. Great, what is Foo supposed to do with that? Foo doesn't know which of *its* users to let use Alice's access token, or Bob's access token!

It's possible to work around this problem. If the authorization server includes the user's "state" token (as it currently does in the redirect) in the direct request to the client, and the state is uniquely identifying for a user, then this information would allow Foo (the client) to correctly associate each request from the server with its own user. However, in other cases (such as when the client is not a uniquely addressable service, but is instead e.g. a static webapp or server-less mobile app on the user's device), it's not even possible for the authorization server (Bar) to communicate with the client (Foo) *except* through the user agent. Similarly, if the state isn't used (it's not essential in every context, though it's recommended in all of them) or isn't stored on the server in a useful way, this wouldn't work.

---

I don't actually *know* why OAuth (which is generally a somewhat "over-engineered" protocol family, in that it tries to have the best solution to every possible use case, at the cost of considerable complexity) does not in fact permit this approach where it would be viable (client has a known, reachable endpoint address *and* includes a uniquely identifying and unpredictable token with every authorization request). As far as I can tell, it has no major security weaknesses. While PKCE does mitigate even the minute threat of an attacker capturing the authorization code before it's used and submitting it to the client as their own, I'm not convinced that the mitigation adds less complexity or more security than the approach above.

However, I have some guesses. First of all, as noted above, PKCE basically solves the problem already, and if it requires some additional complexity on client and server, well, so does this approach. This proposed modification requires a bigger change in the protocol; fundamentally modifying the data flows, rather than simply adding one step to each of client-side and server-side plus an additional parameter to each request and a new error response. PKCE is also usable in more cases (doesn't require a client addressable without routing through the user agent) and thus has been adopted even for clients that can't store client_secret values securely (which used to be limited to the weaker Implicit flow, and mostly wouldn't be able to use this modification). This modification also adds the novel requirement that the authorization server make *outbound* requests; in the current flows, the authorization server need only listen for and respond to inbound requests (from the user agent and the client); that has security implications for hardening the authorization server against attacks. The modification also adds nothing if the user agent is in fact compromised (e.g. by a malicious browser extension) since that's functionally equivalent to the world where the code was stolen by the attacker and used to impersonate the user to the client.

Given all that, this would functionally be an entirely new OAuth flow/grant from the existing ones. Such a thing could be created and standardized, but I'm not sure it *adds* any value beyond the Authorization Code + PKCE flow, which is already standardized and widely adopted.